# Access privileges to SSIS Package but not the tables

Tags: sql-server, ssis

In SQL Server 2005, can I specify only execute permissions to a SSIS package, but restrict access to all tables and other objects in a database? The SSIS package will be updating a few tables however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the package is to be run in the context of the user that is executing the package, it would be tough to update something you don't have permissions for. If your package is run through the SQL Server Agent, it will run as the agent account, and if that has access to update the tables in question, the user without access (if given access to create and/or start jobs) - you should be able to do what you want.